# AWS ELB - file upload takes a long time to complete

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm using an AWS ELB to load balance across a few EC2 instances and part of my site involves a file upload. This file upload takes a long time to complete (~30 seconds for a 1mb file) and is only happening now that I'm using the ELB.

The requests do complete successfully but it drives the average latency up a lot.

Do I have to configure something on the load balancer to allow/speed up file uploads through it?

Comment: Can't answer without more information, but here's my two cents. When using AWS ELB your file does not upload directly to the ec2 instance(s). It uploads to an s3 bucket and then deploys to the ec2 instance. If the upload is taking much longer than normal I would first check how well my internet connection is performing. Finally if you want your services to be available while this process is going you should have multiple (at least 2) ec2 instances in the auto-scaling group and use a batch deployment to update your code (.war or whatever you are using).

Comment: Random ideas: Play with the [idle connection](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-idle-timeout.html) setting or configure [sticky sessions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html). Should not really be an issue, but worth experimenting in case the upload is flicking between backend instances.

Comment: @Theyna uploads that go through the load balancer do not go to an S3 bucket and then to your EC2 instance. The uploads go straight through the load balancer and to the EC2 instance.

Comment: @MarkB ok, I'm not familiar with that deployment method. My mistake. Or are you saying that all uploads go through the load balancer? When I upload to my ELBs the .war I use is in my s3 bucket before it is available on the instances.

Comment: @Theyna I believe you are referring to Elastic Beanstalk. The question is about Elastic Load Balancers. The question is not abount a deployment process.

Comment: @MarkB yes  I was, I am confusing myself with the abbreviations I use and not reading properly, I refer to Beanstalk as ELB and Load Balancers as LB. Thanks for pointing that out.